# Ajax call give partial Validation

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have written this ajax code to validate a form, its working fine but it is checking the only password is empty or not, it's not checking password's else part validation. Where am I wrong! that password regex I have got from online. Is it correct? Please correct me.

```js
$('#login-btn').click(function(event) {
  console.log('hit')

  if (formValidate()) {
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: '/login',
      data: {
        email: $('#id_Email').val(),
        password: $('#id_Password').val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
      },
      success: function(res) {
        var response = $.parseJSON(res)
        $('#login-data').html(response.msg)
        if (response.code == 200) {
          $('#login-data').html(response.msg);
          window.location = "http://localhost:8000";
        }
      },
    })
  }
})

function formValidate() {
  var isValid = true;
  if ($('#id_Email').val() == "") {
    isValid = false
    $('#login-data').html('Please Enter Email Address')
  } else {
    if (!(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test($('#id_Email').val()))) {
      isValid = false;
      $('#login-data').html('Please Enter Valid Email Address')
    }
  }
  if ($('#id_Password').val() == "") {
    isValid = false
    $('#login-data').html('Please Enter Password')
  } else {
    if (!(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[#$@!%&*?])[A-Za-z\d#$@!%&*?]{8,}$/.test($('#id_Password').val()))) {
      isValid = false;
      $('#login-data').html('Password Length Must Be 8 with One Spacial Character & One Digit')
    }
  }
  return isValid;
}
```

Comment: Am I correct in, looking at your code, thinking that the password validation has *nothing to do with the ajax call*?

Comment: The regex doesn't match the wording, "with one spacial character and one digit" - but if you change the wording to "with at least one special character and digit" then it's fine: http://refiddle.com/refiddles/5b9f53e275622d4ca96b0000

Comment: @freedomn-m its not checking password length and characters in it!!

Comment: You make the login+password check *then* you make the ajax call - the ajax call is immaterial to the question and including it the question and tags is confusing.

Comment: @freedomn-m sir i want password length to be 8 char log with atleast one digit and special character... so as per my requirement my written regex is correct or not?

Comment: Yes, add "at least" in front of 8 and in front of "one special".  The regex is:  8 or more characters, with one or more a special character and one or more a digit.  The refiddle link I provided shows this working.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[#$@!%&*?])[A-Za-z\d#$@!%&*?]{8,}$/
```

http://jsbin.com/beyixomuxo/edit?js,console

Comment: Can you explain how this is any different from the regex that OP is already using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?=(?=.*[\d]+.*)(?=.*[A-Za-z]+.*)(?=.*[\\\|\=\+\~\/\-\*\.\?\!\~\&\[\]\(\)\^\$\#\@\{\}]+.*)(?=[\w\\\|\=\+\~\/\-\*\.\?\!\~\&\[\]\(\)\^\$\#\@\{\}]{8,}))
```